# How to convert Array of objects to a single object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

if anyone can help me I will be very grateful =D

How do I convert a set that contains arrays of objects into a single array of objects?

to convert this:

```
(2) [Array(5), Array(4)]
    0: Array(5)
       0: {id:1, name:"A"}
       1: {id:2, name:"B"}
       2: {id:3, name:"C"}
       3: {id:4, name:"D"}
       4: {id:5, name:"E"}
    1: Array(4)
       0: {id:6, name:"F"}
       1: {id:7, name:"G"}
       2: {id:8, name:"H"}
       3: {id:9, name:"I"}
```

in that

```
(1) [Array(9)]
   0: {id:1, name:"A"}
   1: {id:2, name:"B"}
   2: {id:3, name:"C"}
   3: {id:4, name:"D"}
   4: {id:5, name:"E"}
   5: {id:6, name:"F"}
   6: {id:7, name:"G"}
   7: {id:8, name:"H"}
   8: {id:9, name:"I"}
```

Comment: Array.prototype.flat()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) A simple google search brings out tons of answers

Comment: This is called "flattening" an array.  See: https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-flatten-array

Comment: Yessss thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `flat()` mentioned in comments you can use arrays spread syntax:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const merged = [...arr1, ...arr2];
```

Comment: This works, but since the problem specifies that the arrays are elements of an array, you'd have to know ahead of time how many elements it contains, e.g. `[...arr[0], ...arr[1]]`